# Calculate Jerk and Jounce from iPhone accelerometer data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, math, accelerometer, physics

I am trying to calculate Jerk (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics)) and jounce (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jounce) with the acceleration data from the accelerometer. I think I have Jerk figured out, but I am not sure what I am doing for jounce is correct. Can anyone confirm or deny what I am doing is giving me correct values (Do I need to take into consideration time?)

```
#define kFilteringFactor    0.4
float prevAccelerationX;
float prevAccelerationY;
float prevAccelerationZ;

float prevJerkX;
float prevJerkY;
float prevJerkZ;



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

prevAccelerationX = 0;
prevAccelerationY = 0;
prevAccelerationZ = 0;

prevJerkX = 0;
prevJerkY = 0;
prevJerkZ = 0;

[self changeFilter:[LowpassFilter class]];
[[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setUpdateInterval:1.0 / kUpdateFrequency];
[[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:self];
}

// UIAccelerometerDelegate method, called when the device accelerates.
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{
float pax = prevAccelerationX;
float pay = prevAccelerationY;
float paz = prevAccelerationZ;

float pjx = prevJerkX;
float pjy = prevJerkY;
float pjz = prevJerkZ;

prevAccelerationX = acceleration.x - ( (acceleration.x * kFilteringFactor) +
                                  (prevAccelerationX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)) );
prevAccelerationY = acceleration.y - ( (acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor) +
                                  (prevAccelerationY * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)) );
prevAccelerationZ = acceleration.z - ( (acceleration.z * kFilteringFactor) +
                                  (prevAccelerationZ * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)) );

// Compute the derivative (which represents change in acceleration).
float jerkX = ABS((prevAccelerationX - pax));
float jerkY = ABS((prevAccelerationY - pay));
float jerkZ = ABS((prevAccelerationZ - paz));


prevJerkX = jerkX - ( ( jerkX * kFilteringFactor) +
                     (prevJerkX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)));
prevJerkY = jerkY- ( (jerkY * kFilteringFactor) +
                                      (prevJerkY* (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)) );
prevJerkZ = jerkZ - ( (jerkZ * kFilteringFactor) +
                                      (prevJerkZ * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)) );

// Compute the derivative (which represents change in acceleration).
float jounceX = ABS((prevJerkX - pjx));
float jounceY = ABS((prevJerkY - pjy));
float jounceZ = ABS((prevJerkZ - pjz));
}
```

Comment: You could save yourself a lot of work by using vectors.

Answer (score 2):

In order to calculate derivatives, yes, you need to take time into consideration. Basically you can estimate jerk with just (a2-a1)/samplingtime. Its time derivative is similar. Your way of using kFilteringFactor seems weird to me but might work for your particular sampling time. You should not take ABS(), as it is perfectly valid for the derivative to be negative.

However, one big issue is probably going to be low sampling frequency. Sampling frequencies in phones are usually around 60 Hz. That means your actual bandwidth for acceleration is 30 Hz (the Nyquist frequency). Halve that and that's your jerk bandwidth. Halve that and your bandwidth for jounce, namely 7.5 Hz. Roughly speaking. All jerks (still a funny word) over 15 Hz and jounces over 7.5 Hz do not disappear but instead are aliased on top of your results. So not only you miss some information, the information you miss actually causes even more damage to your results. Properly done, you'd need low pass filtering before each derivative.

Answer (score 0):

take several time series points from the acclerometer and perform B-Spline Interpolation and find the control points.
Take those points and utilize a a 3rd degree Berstein polynomial, take its first derivative and feed the control points from the B-Spline solution into the derived polynomial where t is between 0 and 1 (assuming 1 Hz sampling rate .. 0 to 1 interpolates everything in that second of time). Those values will be the Jerk/Jounce. You'll be computing this for front and side and acceleration values.